# How do I edit the html when using a PHP based CMS?

Tags: php, html

I am not experienced outside of HTML and CSS.

I have a site on a less well known CMS called Ushahidi. Editing CSS is fine but right now I need to change an img selection. Currently, an image on a page has the code:

```
<a class="photothumb" rel="lightbox-group1"    href="http://trashswag.com/media/uploads/35_1_1347312096.jpg"><img src="http://trashswag.com/media/uploads/35_1_1347312096_t.jpg"></a>
```

I need to remove the ability of the site to use the second image (note there is a slight difference "_t.jpg" is appended to the second src.

How would I alter the site so as to select the first image only i.e. remove the "_t" string?

Comment: Maybe [http://www.freelancer.com](http://www.freelancer.com) would be a better place for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the image with the `_t` in the name is probably a thumbnail of the first image. What you have there is a small image, that when clicked takes you to a larger image. If you want to display the full-sized image and get rid of the link, just use

```
<img src="http://trashswag.com/media/uploads/35_1_1347312096.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks for writing back Cody. So I want to just use the link above my question is how? I it was an html site I'd just go in and change the <img src...>. Since I am less familiar with CMS and PHP I was unsure how to do this. The CMS must use "rules" that that say when a new picture is added (pictures are user generated) use a thumbnail and a full size depending on what the site visitor has clicked on. I should ask then how do I alter the "rules" that generate the html?

Comment: How you do that is probably going to be specific to your particular CMS. I'm not familiar with the one you mentioned in your question, but usually there is some sort of admin interface where you can edit the templates that generate pages. Does yours have something like that? Or are you talking about editing the source of the CMS software itself?

Comment: I think I need to edit the source of the CMS software as there is nothing int he admin section that allows for editing this. Planning on doing some more research then re-posting a new question. Thanks all the same Cody